# Area of triangle/polygon

Tags: geometry

please see following picture:

[image: triangle]

I am trying to find total area, so far- I was able to determine area of the semi-circles but I cannot figure out the area of the triangle in the middle.

The variables for the circle are L (arc length) and R (radius).

I found Area of each semi-circle is A= L*R/2

[image: square]

On a similar vein, this could happen, and so on.

I found that all I need to figure out is the **length of one side as a function of R and L of the circle**. All sides are equal since all circles are similarly shaped and mirror symmetrical (drawings may not show that exactly).

Any help?

Comment: When you say "all circles are similarly shaped and mirror symmetrical" do you mean that the circles are congruent (i.e. exactly the same size)?

Comment: So you're looking to find the total area of all of the parts covered by at least one circle?  Also, if you have $n$ circles, the diagram is meant to be $n$-fold symmetric about the center?

Comment: @Duncan 1) Yes, they are congruent. 2) I am looking to find the area of the n-gon made from the intersection of the circles. 3) Not sure what you mean, but yes, it is symmetrical about the center. Thanks

Comment: Intersection of the circles?? Really? In the square case the circles don't intersect at all, at least not all together. I guess you might have meant union. In that case, do you want to also include the central area which is not covered by any circle, or just the circle areas?

Comment: I presume that the "variable" L and R are the givens. There are 2 types of arcs in your picture, which one is L? The major or the minor? Also, in your picture, I can see major and minor segments but I don't see any semi-circle.

Comment: @MVG Yes, they do not intersect, But the square is just to aid in my viewing, I basically want the area enclosed by the 4 "semi-circles".

Comment: @MicK L would be the arc from point E to point F (that is one arc) for example, or F to G, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ be the length of one side of the polygon, which is what we want to find (e.g. $EH$ in the second picture). Also let $\theta = \angle{EAH}$.

Then, with $R$ the radius and $L$ the inner arc length ($EH$ for example), we find $\theta$ by dividing $L$ by the circumference of the circle:

$\theta = \dfrac{L}{2\pi R} 2\pi = \dfrac{L}{R}.$

$d = 2R \sin{\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)} = 2R \sin{\left(\dfrac{L}{2R}\right)}.$